# CAS proxy configuration

Tags: url, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy, cas

I have a setup of the following:

1. Proxy server: https://proxy-server.com
2. application server: https://app-server.com
3. and a CAS (sso) server: https://sso-server.com

I can get the following working:

https://proxy-server.com/cas/login?service=https://app-server.com/app

But the problem for this URL is it exposes the actual app-server, which is behind the proxy server.

Ideally, I want the following:

https://proxy-server.com/cas/login?service=https://proxy-server.com/app

My question is:
Is there a way to hide (use post, encrypt targetService part, callback on proxy side, or...) the app-server.com in the URL? since I have a proxy server in front, I don't want to expose the actual app server name.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're running something like Apache mod_proxy on `https://proxy-server.com` then you should be able to hide your app behind it.  Based on your example it looks like you're already doing that with your cas server since your stated your cas login url as `https://proxy-server.com/cas/login`

Following the same idea your app can be reached using `https://proxy-server.com/app`

```
ProxyPass          /cas   https://sso-server.com/cas 
ProxyPassReverse   /cas   https://sso-server.com/cas
ProxyPass          /app   https://app-server.com/app  
ProxyPassReverse   /app   https://app-server.com/app
```

You'd probably have to modify your serviceUrls so they are relate to proxy-server.com

- [ProxyPass And ProxyPassReverse Configuration](http://www.allguru.net/error-solution/proxypass-proxypassreverse-configuration/)
- [Proxy HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)